# Python and BeautifulSoup find text string in html

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Have the following function that checks a certain webpage for a keywoard

```
def checkString():   
    url_a = 'https://launchstudio.bluetooth.com/ListingDetails/50756'
    r_a = requests.get(url_a)
    soup_a = BeautifulSoup(r_a.text)

    for blem in soup_a(text=re.compile(r'RFCOMM')):
        return True

    return False
```

Have verified that my soup_a is the same as the view-source of the url, but it seems that my search will only return results contain within the head tags and have a hard time figuring out why. Any suggestions?

Python version 2.7.5

Comment: Does the page source show the `RFCOMM` string as one, not e.g. `<b>RF</b>comm` or `RF<wbr/>COMM`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass `lxml` to the `BeautifulSoup` class. Also, `return True` will break out of the for-loop if a match is found. Thus, if `RFCOMM` is indeed found in the head tags, the loop will quit and no more matches will be registered. It may be better to use a list comprehension and determine if any matches are found:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import urllib.request as urllib
import re
def checkString():   
   url_a = 'https://launchstudio.bluetooth.com/ListingDetails/50756'
   s = soup(str(urllib.urlopen(url_a).read()), 'lxml')
   return bool([i for i in s(text=re.compile(r'RFCOMM'))])

print(checkString())
```

Output:

```
True
```

Comment: Thanks - do not care if it was found inside the heads tag, but for some reason it would not allow me to find anything outside the head tags. Using "html.parser" as argument for the BeautifulSoup did the trick for me for some reason (guess similar to what lmxl would?)